# The normed is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity

$\| \cdot\|$ is continuous?.

when $\| \cdot\|: X^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ helpme please whit HINT please.

Comment: triangle inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look at the inequality that $\left|\|x\|-\|x_{0}\|\right|\leq\|x-x_{0}\|$.

Comment: Which definition of continuity use?

Comment: Whenever $\epsilon>0$ and $x$ is such that $\|x-x_{0}\|<\epsilon$, then $\left|\|x\|-\|x_{0}\|\right|<\epsilon$, done.

Comment: is this mimilary?
$\forall (z_n \rightarrow z$ in $(X^2, d))$ then $(\| z_n \| \rightarrow \| z\| $in $(\mathbb{R},d))$

Comment: I don't think you need to go into such complicated circumstances, it is just that the open neighbourhood of $x_{0}$ in dealing with such continuity can be restricted to open ball centred at $x_{0}$, because such open balls  constitute the local basis for $x_{0}$.

Comment: You can write the definition that you use with quantifiers please, I understand more so